# Rearranging set relationships

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

One often encounters statements like $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{T}^2\cong\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$. On the other hand, particularly in algebra, one can find relationships like $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{S}^1$. I noticed that these notations suggest multiplication and division and I am wondering if they can be rearranged. For instance, is it valid to "multiply" both sides of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{S}^1$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ to obtain $\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Not in general; in fact $\Bbb R$ is not equivalent to $\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb Z$ in any way that springs to mind.

Comment: They are clearly not isomorphic as groups. $S^1\times\mathbb{Z}$ has nontrivial elements of finite order, $\mathbb{R}$ does not.

Comment: This only works for *sets* up to bijections and homogeneous equivalence relations, i.e. for cardinal numbers when we quotient out by an equivalence relation whose equivalence classes have the same cardinalities.